# Lookup values via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need help looking up row D1 and E1 with columns A1:B via VBA. Basically, I'm making Type (column A) as the row headers and transferring Object (column B) to their corresponding Type.

I was able to create a VBA code to do that but I'm just stuck with the lookup function. The only way I can think of is doing this via Vlookup function but I'm pretty sure that there's a better a more efficient way to do this coz using VBA to input the formula on each row would be tedious and troublesome.

I've tried researching about it but it seems that I'm too noob about it. If any of you can post the most comprehensive way on how to do it, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

here's how the code looks so far.

```
Set SearchTermData = Worksheets("Search Term Data")
Set Data = Worksheets("Data")

Dim AdGrpCount As Variant, CampHeader As Variant

SearchTermData.[A:B].Copy Data.[A1]

With Data

    [A2:A1048576].Copy [C1]
    [C:C].RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    CopyTransposed [C:C].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), [C1]
    [C2:C1048576].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Clear

    AdGrpCount = [B2:B1048576].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    CampHeader = [C1:XFD1].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

            For rowcnt = 2 To AdGrpCount
                check = Application.Match([C1], Cells(rowcnt, 1), 0)
                    If Application.IsNumber(check) Then
                        Cells(rowcnt, 2).Copy Cells(rowcnt, 3)
                    End If
            Next rowcnt
End With
```

Comment: Post the VBA code you came up with, and we should be able to work out what your problems with the `VLookup` are.

Comment: Actually, forget that for a moment.  What are you trying to achieve?  A Lookup is just going to return the first item (e.g. "cellphone" for "Non-Organic").  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please explain your query in details plz, as the question is vague.

Comment: Based on the image I posted. What I'm trying to do is make column A as the row headers in columns D and E and list all the items under those categories. So in column D it should list D1 as "Non-Organic", the header, then list all the non-organic items under it.

My initial idea was to count the number of headers and use it for a loop function that would add the vlookup formula on each cell of each columns but that would slow down the code. 

What I'm asking is, is there a way of doing the lookup for the values without doing the loop of adding the vlookup on each cell of the column?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to create this functionality would be, to put the formula `=IF($A2=D$1,$B2,"")` in cell D2, and to copy this formula to range D2:E15 .